# Why delete a class without virtual dtor is OK if it inherits a class with virtual dtor

Tags: c++, virtual, destructor

Consider below code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

struct Base1
{
    Base1() = default;
    virtual ~Base1() = default;
    //~Base1() = default;
};

struct Base2 : public Base1
{
    Base2()
    {
        printf("%s:%d:%s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);
    }
    ~Base2() // non-virtual destructor
    {
        printf("%s:%d:%s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);
    }
};

struct Derive : public Base2
{
    Derive()
    {
        printf("%s:%d:%s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);
    }
    ~Derive()
    {
        printf("%s:%d:%s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base2> d = std::make_unique<Derive>();
    return 0;
}
```

The class `Base2` has no virtual destructor, but it inherits `Base1` which has a virtual destructor.

The code `std::unique_ptr<Base2> d = std::make_unique<Derive>();` is trying to delete `Base2` on an object of type `Derive`, I was expecting only `Base2`'s dtor is called, but not for `Derive`.

But actually it works fine:

```
main.cpp:15:Base2
main.cpp:27:Derive
main.cpp:31:~Derive
main.cpp:19:~Base2
```

So it looks like as long as the "real" base class (here it's `Base1`) has virtual dtor, all the inherited classes are not required to have virtual dtor, is it?
If yes, where can I find the related document about this?

Comment: That's what virtual means.  The override version is always called regardless of the type of the pointer you use

Comment: Overriding a virtual method, traditionally needs no keyword; formerly the ‘virtual‘ keyword could also be used as an override indicator; now there is the recommended keyword ‘override‘. The dtor is no exception to that rule, but it is a little different in that it is almost always implicitly defined per class if user doesn't prepare one. So tagging the base dtor ‘virtual' affects the entire hierarchy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if a class has a base class whose [destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#Virtual_destructor) is declared as `virtual`, its destructor would be `virtual` too; regardless of declaring it as `virtual` explicitly or not.

> Even though destructors are not inherited, if a base class declares
>   its destructor virtual, the derived destructor always overrides it.
>   This makes it possible to delete dynamically allocated objects of
>   polymorphic type through pointers to base.
>
> ```
> class Base {
>  public:
>     virtual ~Base() { /* releases Base's resources */ }
> };
>
> class Derived : public Base {
>     ~Derived() { /* releases Derived's resources */ }
> };
>
> int main()
> {
>     Base* b = new Derived;
>     delete b; // Makes a virtual function call to Base::~Base()
>               // since it is virtual, it calls Derived::~Derived() which can
>               // release resources of the derived class, and then calls
>               // Base::~Base() following the usual order of destruction
> }
> ```

From the standard, [[class.dtor]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.dtor#13)

(emphasis mine)

> A prospective destructor can be declared virtual ([class.virtual]) or
>   pure virtual ([class.abstract]). If the destructor of a class is
>   virtual and any objects of that class or any derived class are created
>   in the program, the destructor shall be defined. **If a class has a base
>   class with a virtual destructor, its destructor (whether user- or
>   implicitly-declared) is virtual**.

Comment: And if you want to make it non-virtual for derived classes you must add final keyword on it.

Answer (score 6):

Because if it inherits from a class with a virtual destructor, then it has a virtual destructor, even if you don't have to explicitly mark it as `virtual`.

```
~Base2() // actually a virtual destructor
```

Note, if you want to ensure that `~Base2()` is virtual independently of `~Base1()`, then you should mark it as `virtual`. But usually what you want to do is ensure `Base1()` is actually virtual. That can be achieved by use of the `override` specifier:

```
~Base2() override; // fail to compile if ~Base1() is not virtual
```

Comment: Good suggestion on adding `override` for destructor!